# If $A$ and $B$ are closed, then $A+B$ is Borel

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, compactness

I am trying to prove this statement by proving first that $A+B = \{a+b : a \in A, b \in B\}$ is $F_\sigma$.

I am lost, I saw that I had to prove first the case when $A$ and $B$ were compact then $A+B$ was compact but I can't see how this helps.

In any case, is this part of the proof also right then?

If $A$ and $B$ are compact, then for any sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ (in $A$ and $B$ respectively) there is a convergent subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ and $(b_{n_k})$. Therefore for any sequence $(a_n + b_n)$, there is a convergent subsequence $(a_{n_k} + b_{n_k})$ in $A+B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true in the real line.  $A$ and $B$ are both countable unions of compact sets.  The sum of two compact sets is a compact set (your proof of this is OK). So $A+B$ is a countable union of compact sets.  And a compact set is closed.  Conclude that $A+B$ is an $F_\sigma$.

Comment: I don't understand why the proof of $A+B$ is compact given by OP is fine. Convergent subsequences should be $(a_{n_k})$ and $(b_{n_l})$ and $(a_{n_k}+b_{n_l})$ might not converge.

Comment: True, the OP needs work.  So, there is an infinite set $I \subseteq \mathbb N$ so that $(a_n)_{n \in I}$ converges.  Then there is an infinite set $J \subseteq I$ so that $(b_n)_{n \in J}$ coverges.  Finally, $(a_n+b_n)_{n \in J}$ is a convergent subsequence of $(a_n+b_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$.  *Alternate proof*  Addition is continuous, $A \times B$ is compact, so $A+B$ is a continuous image of a compact set, and thus $A+B$ is compact.